# When debugging UWP app the symbol file is not recognized

Tags: debugging, xamarin, uwp

I have a Xamarin UWP app which works correctly when I run it from within Visual Studio. However if I generate and publish the app to the store, it crashes when I perform a certain action (which works when running from Visual Studio). I have used Visual Studio to try and debug the installed version (both by attaching to a running copy and starting it from within Visual Studio), but it does not seem to accept the pdb file that was generated when I built the store version. I obtained the pdb file from the generated appxsym file. How can I debug the installed version?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your local revision is different from the one published on the store. If you want the pdb file to work, you need to have the exact same executable that is published on the store. Do you have this revision in your version control system?

Comment: Have you checked version Automatically increment and includue full pdb symbol files options?

Comment: I am using the pdb file that was generated when the upload package was created. It should match. The executable that I am trying to debug is directly downloaded from the store and came from that same package.

Comment: Actually the package will be compiled again when you upload it to the store.So the local pdb file generated with the upload package is not the exact one. Please create a sideload package and try to reproduce the issue first and then you could use the pdb file in the package to debug about this. Please also make sure you are building and packaging the app in release mode.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it will be compiled again? I created an .appxupload file which appears to contain compiled binary files, not the source. How is it that that can be recompiled by Microsoft once uploaded? That does not really make any sense. Are you saying that it is impossible to debug an app that has been downloaded from the store?

Comment: The online compilation process  is used to adapt to the lowest configured device and the latest policy. Why I'm asking you to debug a sideload package first is to check if the problem is related to store compilation process.

Comment: Actually, I have resolved the particular crashing issue that prompted this question. However this question was not about that specific crash issue but rather how to go about debugging an app that is downloaded from the store and I am still interested in an answer to that for future reference. You seem to be telling me that it is not possible. Correct?

Comment: You could download the pdb file from store (product management->manage package).

Comment: YES, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, please download the pdb file from uwp dev center.

location：product management->manage package.

[image]